# Basic Unix refresher inquiry: ls -ld

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, command-line

I know this is really basic, but I cannot find this information
in the ls man page, and need a refresher:

```
$ ls -ld my.dir
drwxr-xr-x    1 smith users      4096 Oct 29  2011 my.dir
```

What is the meaning of the number 1 after drwxr-xr-x ?
Does it represent the number of hard links to the direcory my.dir?
I cannot remember. Where can I find this information?

Thanks,

John Goche

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to accept answers ... if you have no idea what I'm talking about [click here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679)

Answer (score 4):

I found it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls):

`duuugggooo   (hard link count) owner group    size  modification_date  name`

The number is the hard link count.

If you want a more UNIXy solution, type `info ls`.  This gives more detailed information including:

```
`-l'
`--format=long'
`--format=verbose'
     In addition to the name of each file, print the file type, file
     mode bits, number of hard links, owner name, group name, size, and
     timestamp (*note Formatting file timestamps::), normally the
     modification time.  Print question marks for information that
     cannot be determined.
```

Comment: Yes, but what about for directories? Is it always set to 2, and if so then why?

Answer (score 3):

That is the number of named (hard links) of the file. And I suppose, there is an error here. That must be at least 2 here for a directory.

```
$ touch file
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor 0 Jul 15 10:24 file
$ ln file file-link
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 2 igor igor 0 Jul 15 10:24 file
-rw-r--r-- 2 igor igor 0 Jul 15 10:24 file-link
$ mkdir a
$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor igor 40 Jul 15 10:24 a
-rw-r--r-- 2 igor igor  0 Jul 15 10:24 file
-rw-r--r-- 2 igor igor  0 Jul 15 10:24 file-link
```

As you can see, as soon as you make a directory, you get 2 at the column.

When you make subdirectories in a directory, the number increases:

```
$ mkdir a/b
$ ls -ld a
drwxr-xr-x 3 igor igor 60 Jul 15 10:41 a
```

As you can see the directory has now three names ('a', '.' in it, and '..' in its subdirectory):

```
$ ls -id a ; cd a; ls -id .; ls -id b/..
39754633 a
39754633 .
39754633 b/..
```

All these three names point to the same directory (`inode 39754633`).

Comment: It's true. I also get a 2 for number of hard links for the file when a direcory is created. I also cannot create a hard link for a directory: "mkdir foo; ln foo bar" produces the output "ln: `foo': hard link not allowed for directory". Why is this do you think? Also, the first number after the second "igor" is the number of bytes required to store the file or directory, correct? Thanks, John Goche

Comment: So for a directory number of hard links is always set to 2. Why is this? Why not 1 for instance? Thanks, John Goche

Comment: `hard link not allowed for directory`, that's true, you cannot make hardlinks foe the directories; but if you make subdirectories in a directory, the number of its name increases. That is because eac subdirectoru has `..` in it. `the first number after the second "igor"` -- yes, it's true; that is the sie of a file/directory.

Comment: Not always 2, but 2 as minimum. Because any directory has at least 2 names: its own name and `.` in it. But if you make subdirectories, this number will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to explain why  for directory the initial link count value =2.
Pl. see if this helps.

Any file/directory is indentified by an inode.
Number of Hard Links = Number of references to the inode.

When a directory/file  is created, one directory entry (of the 
form - {myname, myinodenumber}) is created in the parent directory.
This makes the reference count of the inode for that file/directory =1.

Now when a directory is created apart from this the space for directory is also created which by default should be having two directory entries
one for the directory which is created and another for the 
parent directory that is two entries of the form {., myinodenumber}
and {.., myparent'sinodenumber}.

Current directory is referred by "." and the parent is referred by ".." .

So when we create a directory the initial number of Links' value = 1+1=2,
since there are two references to myinodenumber. And the parent's number 
of link value is increased by 1.